# Why is flow complaining that my variable is not a string?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

My code is as follows (I believe this is mostly a typing issue so I don't think the actual code for downloading is relevant here):

```
...
TokenService.getToken(id).then(result => {
  const { read } = result;
  if (typeof read === 'string') {
    download(url_template, name, read, is_watermarked);
  }
});
```

```
**
 * Downloads a file
 * @param {string} urlTemplate The url to download
 * @param {string} name The name of the original file
 * @param {string} readToken The access token
 * @param {boolean} isWatermarked If a file has a watermark
 * @returns {void}
 */
const download = (urlTemplate: string, name: string, readToken: string, isWatermarked: boolean) => {
...
```

But flow keeps complaining with an errorr about deconstructing `read`:

```
Cannot call TokenService.getToken(...).then with function bound to onFulfill because property read is
missing in String [1] in the first argument.
```

The strange thing is, I've logged the variable type of `read` and it comes back as a `string`; so I'm not sure why flow is complaining...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's dive into your error messages:

```
Cannot call TokenService.getToken(...).then with function bound to onFulfill because property read is
missing in String [1] in the first argument.
```

What this error says is that Flow thinks `result` is a String, and thus cannot read property `result.read` because Strings don't have such property ("`property read is missing`"). Instead of logging the variable type of `read`, log it's contents and see if it is a valid String.

The second error

```
Cannot call download with read bound to readToken because object type [1] is incompatible
with string [2].
```

Says that Flow thinks the type of `read` is other than String in this line:

```
download(url_template, name, read, is_watermarked);
```

This is why you should first check if `read` is for sure string, and then try setting it's type or overriding it (in Typescript it would be `(read as string)`, but I don't know how Flow works sadly)

Keep in mind that what you log into the console is a runtime value, and what Flow thinks a variable's type is, is different because it's only trying to guess what the type of variable will be, but it can't know for sure what will occur in the runtime.

## ===========================

## The answer below is incorrect, I left if here so people reading comments to this answer are not confused

The problem is that when you hover over `result` object here,

```
const { read } = result;
```

you will see it's type is not set strongly. To bypass that, when you know your API responses are always correct and under `result.read` you will always find string, you can force strong type of the `read` variable like so:

```
  download(url_template, name, (read as string), is_watermarked);
```

Keep in mind that logging a variable is different than working with Typescript. What you did was to check the *runtime* value, but Typescript only works on *build* level so it is unaware that your API will respond with good object.

Comment: Ahhh I see! That makes sense...I do run into a parsing error when doing `(read as string)` though: `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: Hm, I found a few other posts that seem to suggest that variables in javascript can't be typed; perhaps that's why I'm getting this parsing error? @deaponn

Comment: (Also if it helps, my files are javascript files; not tsx files)

Comment: @user18971245 ah I see, for some reason I thought you are using Typescript. My bad leading you the wrong way!

Comment: @user18971245 I have modified my Answer, have a look. I hope it helps!

Comment: No problem! I should've included that info in my question, thank you! I'll try it out!

Comment: Hm, so I logged what `read` actually was and it is indeed a string. And if I throw in an explicit check for `read` (see edited question above), then I'm left with only the first argument..

Comment: Ah I see...if I add an explicit return type (in my case the result would be an `Object`) for my `getToken` function, then I don't get flow errors!

Comment: @user18971245 I'm glad you were able to solve the issue! Stay on track and become better every day :) I hope I helped you on your way to solve the issue :)